# Добавление данных в DataGridView. Автоинкремент

Tags: c#, база-данных, winforms, datagridview, ms-access

В базе данных (MS Access) таблица с двумя столбцами: Код и Название. Код на автоинкременте. Когда добавляешь значение (руками) в столбец Название, Код принимает отрицательное значение. Почему и как исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: первое что просится - перепроверьте свойства столбца Код, просто так не бывает)

Comment: Если сделать Update, в БД добавится нормально. Она сама сделает инкримент. Сам DataGridView показывает такие коды.

Comment: Как данные изначально попадают в этот грид? Осуществляется привязка данных к DataSet/DataTable? Если да, то какие значения заданы для [AutoIncrementStep](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.autoincrement?view=netframework-4.8)?

Comment: В данном случае через Источник данных подключенный через Visual Studio. Выходит, что ему не передается свойство "автоинкримента". Я бы мог сделать Update. Тогда БД сделает инкримет. Можно обновить данные, тогда в Код придет верное значение. Но как обновить отображение и не потерять значение в чекбоксах? Можно обновить только одно строку?

Comment: Или где-то можно задать инкримент?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Новые строки на стороне клиента создаются с временным отрицательным значением идентификатора, потому что [AutoIncrementStep](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.autoincrementstep?view=netframework-4.8) задаётся равным -1. Это гарантирует, что оно никогда не совпадёт с существующим идентификатором в базе данных, поскольку все другие строки имеют положительные идентификаторы.

Если сразу создавать положительное значение, то вставка в БД может завершиться с ошибкой.

Затем, когда строка вставляется в БД, создается постоянный уникальный идентификатор на стороне БД. После чего он извлекается при обновлении данных.

Использовать просто пустое значение (0, null и т. п.) на клиенте не получится в том случае, если имеются отношения предок-потомок между таблицами в датасете.

То есть это нормальное поведение и оно не должно вас беспокоить.

[Retrieving Identity or Autonumber Values](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-identity-or-autonumber-values).

Comment: Хорошо, отрицательное понятно почему. Но я бы хотел брать Код от нового Названия из DataGridView (потому что в нем CheckBox'ы). Где стоит галка - берем код. Но после Update для DataSet - Grid все еще показывает отрицательный Код. И по запросу `dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[1].Value` отдает отрицательное. Поэтому приходится делать новый `TableAdapter.Fill`. И только потом забирать Код. Уже нормальный. Можно ли менее крупной командой обновлять ячейки с отрицательными значениями?

Comment: @Owl - Новые настоящие значения нужно получить из БД sql-запросом select. Именно его выполняет TableAdapter.Fill. Иначе никак. Можно конечно не все строки повторно читать, а только вставленные.

Comment: Не подскажите как читать только выставленные?

Comment: @Owl - я же ссылку дал в ответе. Там это расписано для разных провайдеров. Т. к. у вас Access, то вероятно, нужен этот раздел: [Retrieving Microsoft Access Autonumber Values](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-identity-or-autonumber-values#retrieving-microsoft-access-autonumber-values).